# Xamarin forms Context menu with Icon

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I done a few research can't seems to find a good solution for this.
I am trying to implement a context menu with Icon in ios (xamarin forms) only the text shows and not the icon.

my code so far

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
<MenuItem x:Name="options" Text="Options" Icon="more" />
<MenuItem x:Name="email" Text="Email" Icon="email" />
<MenuItem x:Name="phone" Text="Phone" Icon="phone" />
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

looking for something like this below.

[image: Context menu with icon]

Comment: XF doesn't support icon with MenuItem in iOS.  Only in Xamarin.iOS(not Forms) you can achieve it with `UIContextualAction`.

Comment: @ColeXia thanks I'll try that.

Comment: too far down the project to separate them now.